# How do I performance test my ASP.NET MVC website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, apachebench, requests-per-second

I'm wanting to find out how many requests/sec my asp.net mvc site (and asp.net mvc api) can handle. I've [googled](http://www.google.com.au/search?hl=en&q=asp.net+mvc+performance+test&meta=) for some help and stumbled on this [great slide show](http://www.slideshare.net/rudib/aspnet-mvc-performance) which talks about exactly the things i'm after. They also use a product called [ApacheBench](http://freshmeat.net/projects/apachebench/) to hit the website. That application's website list it as a unix-type product. If it's a perl app, I'm also not going to install perl OR apache.

I'm using Visual Studion 2008 Team Suit edition on Windows 7 RTM.

Does anyone know of any programs I could use to help figure out what are the response times for 'x' number of hits to a url, etc?

thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a Windows binary for Apache Bench. You could download [Apache Web Server for Windows](http://mir2.ovh.net/ftp.apache.org/dist/httpd/binaries/win32/apache_2.2.13-win32-x86-no_ssl.msi) and extract ab.exe and abs.exe from it.

Comment: does ab.exe require apache to be installed? what's the difference between ab.exe and abs.exe ? also, can someone upload the ab.exe and abs.exe to a file upload site ? :)

Comment: No, they are completely. I've extracted them from the MSI without installing Apache and they work fine. As to uploading the executables to a site there might be some licensing issues.

Comment: +1 - I've used ab.exe extensively.  It's very easy to use and provides useful metrics.

Comment: You could use this tool http://blogs.pingpoet.com/overflow/archive/2005/11/16/14995.aspx to extract files from MSI without needing to install anything.

Comment: @Darin (again). Bummer : i keep getting this error when i'm using it :( "Benchmarking www.google.com.au [through http:0] (be patient)...apr_sockaddr_info_get() for http: Unknown error (10105)" I've only extracted the ab.exe program from the msi, manually. :( :(

Answer (score 1):

You could also try [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) , I found it very useful because of it's feature for recording request.

It also has got advanced features like, sending the requests from multiple machines and controlling it from a centralized location.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/).  They've got a windows binary [here](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html)

You could also check out [this](http://www.opensourcetesting.org/performance.php) page listing open source performance testing tools, including some Windows specific ones, like [dieseltest](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dieseltest/)

Edit, added curl example

```
curl -s "http://example.com/index.html?[1-1000]"
```

This will retrieve the URL 1000 times.  My DOS scripting isn't up to much so I don't know how to time this.  If this were a *nix shell I'd just do

```
time curl -s "http://example.com/index.html?[1-1000]"
```

Comment: cURL looks pretty good. um .. would you know how i could use it to grab see the response time for .. say 100 concurrent hits to a URL/server?

Comment: @Pure.Krome,  I don't know an easy way to get curl to read the URL's concurrently.  You should be able to script it though